# docx4j with weblogic Bad [Content_Types].xml Exception

Tags: weblogic, docx4j

how to solve this Exception when I use docx4j with weblogic to open docx file.
follow is my code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage templatePackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .load(getDocxInputTream());
```

Exception is :

```
2013-04-03 18:10:29 ERROR ContentTypeManager:698 - java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:699)
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)

            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:213)
            at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(Wordpr ocessingMLPackage.java:184)
```

Thanks advance!

Comment: Have you had a look at the discussions at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/weblogic-f25/

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Is JAXB in your classpath if you are using java 1.5?

Comment: jdk 1.6.x docx4j 2.8.1