# Docx4J Bad [Content_Types].xml with WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, jaxb, java-6, docx4j, weblogic12c

I'm wondering if anyone has had the same problem with the setup:

1. WebLogic 12c
2. Docx4J 2.8.1
3. Java EE 6

I tried to get the content of a certain Microsoft Word 2007 Document with Docx4J but got an error like the following:

When I try to do:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage package = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File((path));
```

it will throw exception like:

```
2013-06-05 15:29:12.0283 ERROR Thread-18 org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils – name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal@2b0bf3 .. trying RI.
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapper@2a3c7c
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:590)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.tryUsingRI(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:73)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:64)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:56)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:666)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
2013-06-05 15:29:12.0455 ERROR Thread-18 org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils – JAXB: neither Reference Implementation nor Java 6 implementation present?
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper value: org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapper@2a3c7c
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.java:590)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.tryUsingRI(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:73)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.getPrefixMapper(NamespacePrefixMapperUtils.java:64)
at org.docx4j.jaxb.Context.<clinit>(Context.java:56)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:666)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
```

As mentioned above, I am using JDK 6, so that should've been an impossible message.
But the above message is suppressed internally by Docx4J, and instead throws the following exception:

```
2013-06-05 15:46:38.0392 ERROR Thread-18 com.jonathan.business.catalog.impl.ProductCatalogServiceImpl – Bad [Content_Types].xml
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:699)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:666)
... 12 more
2013-06-05 15:46:38.0392 ERROR Thread-18 com.jonathan.business.catalog.impl.ProductCatalogServiceImpl – Bad [Content_Types].xml
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Bad [Content_Types].xml
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:699)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.process(LoadFromZipNG.java:206)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.LoadFromZipNG.get(LoadFromZipNG.java:193)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:301)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:245)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:195)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:178)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:666)
... 12 more
```

[I tried this](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/weblogic-f25/docx4j-with-weblogic-bad-xml-t1501.html) as suggested in Docx4J forum, but no use.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785476/docx4j-with-weblogic-bad-content-types-xml-exception) also yield no answer.

Java 6 should have it's own implementation of JAXB internally, but so far I've tried:

1. not putting any jaxb jar inside the library
2. putting jaxb jar of versions: 2.1.7, 2.2.4, also 2.2.6, neither works.

Also if it's of any help, the same method works if I run it from void main, it just doesn't work if it's executed from WebLogic server, so I'm convinced that there's class loading problem.

Comment: If it is a class loading problem, you may need to set the order in which they are loaded for your application. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187581/how-to-set-order-of-jars-in-weblogic

Answer (score 0):

To get docx4j working with Weblogic 12c, reportedly you can either upgrade eclipselink, or switch to the JAXB reference implementation.

To upgrade Eclipselink, see http://www.docx4java.org/forums/weblogic-f25/how-to-update-to-eclipselink-2-5-in-web-t1574.html

http://www.docx4java.org/forums/weblogic-f25/classcastexception-in-weblogic-12c-t1643.html#p5675 suggests switching to the JAXB RI is a better approach, for now anyway.

Note that to use the Eclipselink JAXB implementation with docx4j, you should use docx4j 3 beta or later.