# Migrate eclipseLink of Toplink

Tags: weblogic, shared-libraries, eclipselink, toplink

I want to change **eclipseLink 2.3.2** to **eclipseLink 2.4.2** I tryed with this [tutorial](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/10/updating-eclipselink-in-weblogic.html) but doesn´t work, with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421790/how-to-replace-eclipselink-2-3-2-with-eclipselink-2-5-in-weblogic-server-12c) but I think that he use Weblogic 12.1.2 ( I use **Weblogic 12.1.1**), with [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/weblogic#DI_1.1:_Alternative_4:_Global_Level_Shared_Library), and I read [this](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2524817#10959732) and I don´t know which library change that this works in Module and I add jar in *domain/lib* and doesnt work. Any Idea???

My shared library:
[image]

application.xml:
`<application>`
`<display-name>eclipselink-shared-lib</display-name>`
`<module>`
`<java>/lib/eclipselink.jar</java>`
`</module>`
`</application>`

MANIFEST:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_04-b21 (Oracle Corporation)
Extension-Name: eclipselink-shared-lib
Specification-Version: 2.4.2`

weblogic-application:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">`
   `<prefer-application-packages>`
   `<package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.*</package-name>`
  `</prefer-application-packages>`
`</wls:weblogic-application>`

And weblogic-application ear use :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.4/weblogic-application.xsd">`
    `<library-ref>`
       `<library-name>eclipselink-shared-lib</library-name>`
    `</library-ref>`
`</wls:weblogic-application>`

And now gives me this *error*: **[WARNING] weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 9 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application SIUCOM_EAR on AdminServer.
Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
java.io.IOException: C:\oracle\Middleware12c\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user\SIUCOM_EAR\4q1ire\lib\eclipselink.jar (El sistema no puede hallar el archivo especificado) with : C:\oracle\Middleware12c\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user\PROJECT_EAR\4q1ire\lib\eclipselink.jar**

It´s true that path doesn´t exist, correct path are: **C:\oracle\Middleware12c\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user\eclipselink-shared-lib\276ipa\lib\eclipselink.jar**

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?  It could just be a simple mistake in the configuration you used and missed.  Have you gotten a shared library to work in WebLogic before?

Comment: It's kind of asking a lot to have people check out 4 different links to understand your question. Maybe you can post the errors and some more info in the question.

Comment: It´s my first time use shared library. I update my code @Chris and   better_use_mkstemp sorry to abuse of links

Comment: I resolved, I change application.xml **<java>/lib/eclipselink.jar</java>** to **<java></java>**. Do you think is better delete question or not?

Comment: Answer might be useful to someone else, as it confirms some of the information you collected initially.